# Buttons Not Responding After Being Set Inactive and Reactivated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 2019.1.1a and I believe it's still in Beta. I'm designing a 2D game.
Anyway, I have stored all of my UI elements inside of an empty game object within the canvas.

Quit-UI is an empty game object. I set it inactive from start, which makes all GUI vanish as intended.

```
[Header("UI Quit Controls")]
[SerializeField]
private GameObject quitImg;
[SerializeField]
private Button exit, resume;

private void Start()
{
    player = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    quitImg.SetActive(false);

}
```

quitImg is set in my inspector as the empty game object Quit-UI.

[image]

Quit-BG is my Red-ish UI background image, and Quit-FG is my Black foreground image, and QuitTxt is actually my text image "Do your wish to quit", not a Text UI.
[image]

This UI is set active inside of an update function when Escape is pushed down. This action reveals all of the related UI because the game object is set to true:

```
 void Update()
      {

          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {

        quitImg.SetActive(true);           

    }

        }
```

I have the buttons OnClick() set to functions inside of my PlayerMove script script.
The Quit Game Button:

[image]

```
  public void ExitGame()
{

    SceneManager.LoadScene(1);

}
```

The Resume Game button:

[image]

```
  public void ResumeGame()
{

    quitImg.SetActive(false);
    exit.enabled = false;
    resume.enabled = false;

}
```

So my problem is that the buttons are unresponsive to click. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I always use such a structure to enable and disable panels and buttons  and never had a problem.

The only moment where I see a problem in your code is that when you do `ResumeGame` you disable both `Button` components

```
exit.enabled = false;
resume.enabled = false;
```

but you never enable them again.

However you can still see their UI because the `Image` component is not disabled.

To avoid this kind of "misunderstanding" in general you should rather use the buttons' [`interactable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-interactable.html) property like

```
exit.interactable = false;
resume.interactable = false;
```

This keeps the `Button` component intact, not clickable but instead visually "blocked" so e.g. grayed out by default. This is way better from both User and Developer perspective.

---

However in your case the buttons are children of the object you disable

=> So the buttons anyway will not be interactable/visible anymore so it is enough to only set the `quitImg` inactive and completely get rid of the two lines

```
exit.enabled = false;
resume.enabled = false;
```

Comment: ResumeGame() is actually my Cancel button. So when it pops up "Do you wish to quit" Yes/No the ResumeGame() would the equivalent of the No button, in this example.So I would need the elements to be set inactive. However, I discovered that I don't need to disable the buttons because disabling quitImg done that for me. Unfortunately, even after removing the exit and resume variables, I'm still having the same problem. I even tried creating a new canvas and put the quit GUI on that. Then only disabled the QuitGUI canvas. Same results.

Comment: Are they working before you disable the object? From your script I don't see why this should happen .. might be a bug but it's very unlikely that something that basic suddenly shouldn't be working anymore

Comment: I see what you're saying now about the button is disabled but the image is not. I'm going to try your advice tomorrow after work. I will let you know. Thanks very much for the response!

Comment: And yes, both buttons were tested before I implemented the disabling/enabling. The buttons don't react to the mouse at all. No highlight or click/press. 100% non-responsive. Debug.Log() returns no information either. May RaycastTarget is checked and Interactable is checked. It's like you said, the image is enabled but the buttons are not. I'll look more into it tomorrow.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem and posted it, but there is a lot of useful information in your answer here, and I learned a few new things from you. I thank you for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

This really picked my brain! However, the solution was very, very simple. (Just took forever for me to find out the issue lol)

I had deleted my event system which I had no idea what this was. To fix this, I right-clicked on the canvas, selected UI, and EventSystem. The buttons functionality have returned and the code works to perfection.